# Which Destruction spells benefit from the "Impact" (Dual Cast Stagger) perk?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Destruction skill tree's "Impact" perk (req: 40 skill) has the following description:

> Most Destruction spells will stagger an opponent when dual cast.

Which spells qualify?

Comment: I know for certain that: the Novice-level spells (Flames, Sparks, and Frostbite) can't cause stagger, and the Apprentice-level bolt spells (Firebolt, Ice Spike, Lightning Bolt) can cause stagger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strategy guide confirms your findings: the only spells not affected by it are *Flames*, *Sparks*, and *Frostbite*. Every other dual-cast spell will cause stagger.

*However*, after some testing and [checking with the UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction#Perks), it's not accurate. Here's what I've found *is* benefited by *Impact*:

- **Apprentice-level direct damage:** *Firebolt*, *Ice Spike*, and  *Lightning Bolt*
- **Adept-level direct damage:** *Fireball*, *Ice Storm*, *Chain Lightning*
- **Expert-level direct damage:** *Incinerate*, *Icy Spear*, and *Thunderbolt*

Things that are *not* affected by *Impact*:

- **Novice-level direct damage:** *Flames*, *Frostbite*, and *Sparks*
- **Master-level area-of-effect spells:** *Fire Storm*, *Blizzard*, *Lightning Storm*
- **Cloaks:** *Flame Cloak*, *Frost Cloak*, and *Lightning Cloak*
- **Runes<sup>1</sup>:** *Fire Rune*, *Ice Rune*, and *Lightning Rune*
- **Specials:** *Arniel's Convection*, *Vampiric Drain* (can't be dual-casted anyway)
- **Walls:** *Wall of Flames*, *Wall of Frost*, *Wall of Storms*

So, 9 spells affected, 17 that aren't. Definitely not "most" Destruction spells even if you included Runes.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup>Runes have an inherent knock-back effect: they could be affected by *Impact*, but it doesn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: It may be because the first spells are not impacting anything, unlike bolts.

Comment: @Kordos I did some testing of my own tonight to confirm what the strategy guide says: cloaks don't count, and *Impact* doesn't seem to matter for runes (they knock back enemies anyway).