# What are the advantages and disadvantages of dual-wielding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know pros and cons of dual wielding; both for spells and weapons. Please use specific examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For weapons:
Pros:

- can get up to 4 weapon effects onto a pair of weapons.
- More DPS as you attack faster with duel wielding perks

Cons:

- can't block
- can't bash (shields/two handed weapons lets you bash)
- need to find two good weapons instead of one

For dual casting spells, you'll want to [look here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35954/dual-casting-spells/36142#36142).

Comment: Or you could, you know, make your weapons...