# Which is better; dual-wielding or fighting with a shield and weapon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages and disadvantages of dual-wielding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38352/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-dual-wielding)

I want a comparison between dual-wielding one-handed weapons and fighting with a shield and one-handed weapon. I would like the comparison to include:

1. Which is easier at lower levels?
2. Which will benefit more at higher level?
3. Which is easier to use when fighting dragons?
4. Definitive answer on which one is better, with reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Dual wielding is easier as you can take care of enemies faster thus you take less damage.
2. At higher level it all depends on the gear you have but for taking care of thing a bit faster go with dual wielding.
3. Shield and one-handed weapon is best for dragons as the fight will be a little bit longer and more concentrated plus it helps with blocking and higher armor bonus.
4. I suggest dual wielding as its easier and faster to just take care of the enemy before they have a chance to do massive damage to you and it speeds up the fight, plus i think it looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

Dual wielding will start to get better when you get the speed upgrade in your perks and if you got a high smithing so you can upgrade both weapons.